# How to count one column, having a condition where an element is null and another where the element is not null? everything grouped by another element

Tags: sql, oracle

i have to count 1 column by two condition resulting 2 columns, grouped by another column. I'll show you:

```
SELECT cy.Name, COUNT(noa.GZ_Aparat_ID), COUNT(noa.GZ_Aparat_ID)
  FROM GZ_Nominalizare_Aparat noa 
  INNER JOIN GZ_Nominalizare no ON (no.GZ_NOMINALIZARE_ID = noa.GZ_NOMINALIZARE_ID)
  INNER JOIN GZ_AcordAcces aa ON (aa.GZ_ACORDACCES_ID = no.GZ_ACORDACCES_ID)
  INNER JOIN GZ_Abonament ab ON (ab.GZ_ABONAMENT_ID = aa.GZ_ABONAMENT_ID)
  INNER JOIN GZ_PunctConsum pc ON (pc.GZ_ABONAMENT_ID = ab.GZ_ABONAMENT_ID)
  INNER JOIN GZ_IU iu ON (iu.GZ_PUNCTCONSUM_ID = pc.GZ_PUNCTCONSUM_ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C_BPartner_Location bplo ON (ab.C_BPartner_Location_ID = bplo.C_BPARTNER_LOCATION_ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C_Location lo ON (bplo.C_Location_ID = lo.C_Location_ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C_City cy ON (lo.C_City_ID = cy.C_City_ID)
GROUP BY cy.Name
```

> Firt COUNT must contain the counts of noa.GZ_Aparat_ID where iu.GZ_DataPIF IS NULL
>   AND Second COUNT where iu.GZ_DataPIF IS NOT NULL

Comment: does the first `WHERE` need to be `SELECT`? tell me its a typo?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  Might help if there's something native to your platform.

Comment: mate....your question is very unclear and lacks detail...showing only SQL wont help...please use some *plain english* too or your question might get closed..... :)

Comment: It does not have to be select...BhupeshC

Comment: I use Oracle DB Andrew...

Comment: "mate"...what aren't you understanding here?

Comment: @Andrew :  haha..sarcasm...what i am fumbling on is that u just pasted a query and mild *what is the query* thing....m poor in solving such low info thing...wait while some one else post answers...mean while +1 to your question ( *and sarcasm* ) to counter balance  :)

Comment: @Andrew: you can have an inner sql with all the joins, and three selected fields, cy.name and (say) count1 and count2. Define count1 as 1 when iu.GZ_DataPIF IS NULL and 0 otherwise, using a case statement. Similarly count2 will be defined as the reverse. Then in the outer sql you can group by name and select name, SUM(count1), sum(count2).

Comment: I tried your version too. It also works! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if my syntax is quite right for oracle but it's not too dissimilar.

```
SELECT cy.Name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN noa.GZ_Aparat_ID is NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN  noa.GZ_Aparat_IDis NOT NULL THEN 1
                  END) as COUNTNONNULL, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN noa.GZ_Aparat_ID is NULL THEN 1
                  WHEN  noa.GZ_Aparat_ID is NOT NULL THEN 0
                  END) as COUNTNULL
  FROM GZ_Nominalizare_Aparat noa 
  INNER JOIN GZ_Nominalizare no ON (no.GZ_NOMINALIZARE_ID = noa.GZ_NOMINALIZARE_ID)
  INNER JOIN GZ_AcordAcces aa ON (aa.GZ_ACORDACCES_ID = no.GZ_ACORDACCES_ID)
  INNER JOIN GZ_Abonament ab ON (ab.GZ_ABONAMENT_ID = aa.GZ_ABONAMENT_ID)
  INNER JOIN GZ_PunctConsum pc ON (pc.GZ_ABONAMENT_ID = ab.GZ_ABONAMENT_ID)
  INNER JOIN GZ_IU iu ON (iu.GZ_PUNCTCONSUM_ID = pc.GZ_PUNCTCONSUM_ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C_BPartner_Location bplo ON (ab.C_BPartner_Location_ID = bplo.C_BPARTNER_LOCATION_ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C_Location lo ON (bplo.C_Location_ID = lo.C_Location_ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C_City cy ON (lo.C_City_ID = cy.C_City_ID)
GROUP BY cy.Name
```

Comment: Working great, just changed noa.GZ_Aparat_ID with iu.GZ_DataPIF in SUM